# How to compile orson chart library for Swing app

Tags: java, swing, orson-charts

I want to use orson chart (3d chart) in my Swing application with netBeans IDE.
I am a beginner in java, and I dont know how to compile orson chart library and make a jar file out of it, so I can use it in a project in NetBeans.

This is the link to orson chart 3d:
https://github.com/jfree/orson-charts

What should I do to have a jar file for using in my project(netBeans IDE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be to download the precompiled jar file from mvn repository:

[Orson Charts at mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.object-refinery/orsoncharts/1.6)

Comment: Hi Mr Gibert,Thanks for your answer man.but ho do I start with this amazing library? This link dont work for me,so what should I do?     http://www.jroller.com/dgilbert/entry/creating_3d_charts_in_java

Comment: Oh no, jroller seems to have disappeared.  Try the demo code here https://github.com/jfree/orson-charts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/orsoncharts/demo/swing/BarChart3DDemo1.java (you might need to grab a couple more classes from the GitHub repo).

Comment: Bonus: https://web.archive.org/web/20170706155628/http://www.jroller.com/dgilbert/entry/creating_3d_charts_in_java

Comment: very thanks ,Mr Gilbert. but I have a question. Can I use orson chart3D for real time plotting (area,surface,barChart ,...? I do this for jfree chart with line type.please guide me.beset regard.